# Change PYTHONPATH so that mypy can find local module

Tags: python, mypy, pythonpath

My project is structured as follows:

```py
$ tree . -I venv
.
├── mydir
│   └── __init__.py
├── myotherdir
│   └── t.py
└── t.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

Both `t.py` and `myotherdir/t.py` have the same content:

```
$ cat t.py 
import mydir
$ cat myotherdir/t.py 
import mydir
```

Now, if I run `mypy t.py`, then all works fine:

```
$ mypy t.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

However, if I run it from inside `myotherdir`, then it's unable to find `mydir`:

```
$ cd myotherdir/
$ mypy t.py 
t.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'mydir'
t.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I was expecting that I would be able to solve this by modifying PYTHONPATH - however, that didn't work:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=.. mypy t.py 
t.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'mydir'
t.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can I let `mypy` recognise `mydir` when I'm running inside `myotherdir`?

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using bash....

Comment: Does this help? https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#finding-imports

Comment: @BallpointBen yes, thank you, setting MYPYPATH was enough to solve the issue